# Making a Native ELM module with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, native, elm

I've been playing around with Elm for a couple of days and I wanted to make a port of Moment.JS, since I've seen a lack of libraries for what I wanted, and Moment just has everything that I need.

The thing is that I always face the same error. I have Moment.JS in my Native folder (it is named MomentJS.js) and another file called Moment.js (my wrapper). The problem is that when I call moment in Moment.js, I get an error saying that moment is not defined.

I've tried to import MomentJS.js in my elm file as well, before and/or after Moment.js. I've also tried to copy the whole JS into Moment.js and add my wrapper at the end of it. None of this things worked. You know what could I do? I've been looking for similar repos on the internet but I've never seen a module that has a wrapper and another JS file just for the native library.

This is my Moment.js code:

```
var _user$project$Native_Moment = (function() {

    var moment = require('moment');


    var format = function ( format, date ) {
        return moment().format();
    }

    return {
        format: format
    };

})();
```

and my Moment.elm code:

```
module Moment exposing (format)

{-| A module desc

@docs format

-}

import Native.MomentJS
import Native.Moment

{-| Call the default `Moment.js` format method
-}
format : String -> String -> String
format fm dt = Native.Moment.format fm dt
```

The last thing that I tried was to download Moment from npm, copy its folder from the node_modules folder to my Native folder and do `moment = require('moment')` but I got `TypeError: fun(...) is not a function`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `require` won't work like this. Does it work if you copy-paste the whole moment.js code after `var _user$project$Native_Moment = (function() {` and remove the `require` line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some digging, what you are looking to do is completely possible yes! :) However, it won't be a simple copy paste. Look at the source you posted [here](https://github.com/eticav/elm-pouchdb/blob/issue1/src/Native), it will require mapping every function to the native elm functions, i'd recommend starting small with this conversion.

First, Get a simple hello world Native example work, see [here](https://github.com/gabrielperales/elm-native-module)

Secondly, add in some of the simpler functions from moment.js one by one, i'd recommend starting with moment\src\lib\format\format.js

Lastly, I know this isn't what you want to hear, but if you really want to write javascript in elm, maybe Elm isn't what you are looking for? I really can't imagine converting an entire library similar to Moment.js would be simpler than creating your own Elm library inspired by Moment.js

Either way, best of luck! Seems like a fun challenge either way :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two **supported** ways for Elm and JavaScript to talk to each other: ports and flags. Both are asynchronous and will be awkward for your needs.

https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html

Should you write native code? Elm's creator [says no](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!searchin/elm-dev/kernel%7Csort:relevance/elm-dev/bAHD_8PbgKE/X-z67wTdCAAJ).

So the best path forward is to use one of the existing time/date libraries or write what you need yourself.

Comment: I've already implemented Moment with ports but I wanted to do it through native. And I've found that what I have in my mind is not impossible: https://github.com/eticav/elm-pouchdb/blob/issue1/src/Native Here, they have a js file with the original JS Framework, and then the wrappers. Even if it is useless, at least I want to know what is going on xD

Comment: Evan said no to this! https://github.com/elm-lang/package.elm-lang.org/issues/200#issuecomment-314296828 This isn't helpful to the S.O. community who should all be clear of the fact that this is not (nor ever will be) supported.

Comment: I don't think that Evan's views on native modules or lack of support make this an unhelpful question. I understand that the Elm community aims to direct users to Ports and Flags for JS interop but, this is not a question about JS interop. The question explicity asks about native modules. It is worth noting that native modules do not have the support of the people developing Elm, but I don' thtink the correct answer to the question present here is "No". Do you?

Comment: @TylerNickerson I've listened to podcasts where Evan makes himself quite clear, and explains with excellent arguments, that he believes this is a bad idea for Elm and where it's headed over the next years (and decades). I'm interested in preserving those ideas because I think they're more important than this temporary hack. I also don't want people landing on this question thinking "this is how Elm works" and wasting their time with a temporary hack.

Comment: @z5h I agree with what you are saying. However, I disagree that making native/kernel a bad word is how to achieve the desired results. Questions like this still have value for people who want to have a better idea of how modules that lean on native/kernel code work or try playing with it themselves.

Comment: @TylerNickersonI think it's probably good that people can come here and read this discussion and decide for themselves. I understand what I'm arguing for is a perspective.